# Mocked method returns null

Tags: .net, silverlight, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a simple test method in my Silverlight project:

```
[TestMethod]
[Tag("User")]
public void ViewModel_NewUserAdded_DefaultCulturesLoaded()
{
    //setup
    Mock<INameService> mockNameService = new Mock<INameService>();
    MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
    mockNameService
        .Setup(m => m.DefaultCultures(It.IsAny<Action<LoadOperation<kk_mp_name>>>()))
        .Returns(new Mock<OperationBase>(null).Object);
    viewModel.ContextName = mockNameService.Object;

    //action
    Messenger.Default.Send(-1, "New User Added");

    //verify
    mockNameService.Verify(
        (mo) => mo.DefaultCultures(It.IsAny<Action<LoadOperation<kk_mp_name>>>()),
        Times.Exactly(1));
}
```

There DefaultCultures method always returns null instead of new mock-object.
What I doing wrong?

Comment: The Mock would return a default value (e.g. null) in case a call is made for which an expectation has not been set.. So could you check if the call is being made as expected - e.g. if the argument is different i.e. does not match the constraint.

Comment: The method signature in interface is: `OperationBase DefaultCultures(Action<LoadOperation<kk_mp_name>> callback);` So it have too match with: `It.IsAny<Action<LoadOperation<kk_mp_name>>>()`. Simply you couldn't do otherwise...

Comment: = Try making it a strict mock.. you should get a better error description. Because if a call without an explicit expectation, it would throw an exception instead of returning null. Check the moq docs on how to make it a strict mock.

Comment: Nope, this doesn't help. The mock is created without an errors, but still returns null instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it looks like

```
var mockNameService = new Mock<INameService>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

didn't help much.

So my next point of query would be to ask why you're passing in Null here.

```
new Mock<OperationBase>(null).Object
```

Can you post the code for OperationBase ?

Comment: `OperationBase` is a simply abstact class in `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client` namespace. Here null is a constructor parameter for OperationBase. If I call `new Mock<OperationBase>(null).Object` in debug (trough Debug Immediate or Quick Watch), then I'll get actual OperationBase-mocked instance but in running code I'm not. From there is my guess that Setup does not work properly...

Comment: If I call it like `new Mock<OperationBase>(MockBehavior.Strict, null).Object` then the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Is `Messenger.Default.Send` using the mock object you set on `viewModel.ContextName`? If you step into the code to the point where you expect the `DefaultCultures` to be invoked, you can check the concrete type of `ContextName` to ensure it is the mock instance.

I also find it helpful to add a `.Callback` on the mock set up, on which to set a breakpoint and ensure that the method is being invoked:

```
MainViewModel viewModel = new MainViewModel();
mockNameService
    .Setup(m => m.DefaultCultures(It.IsAny<Action<LoadOperation<kk_mp_name>>>()))
    .Callback((Action<LoadOperation<kk_mp_name>> a) =>
     {
         ; // Set breakpoint here
     })
    .Returns(new Mock<OperationBase>(null).Object);
```